# Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?

Tags: python, subprocess, parent

I'm running a script that executes a number of executables by using

```
subprocess.call(cmdArgs,stdout=outf, stderr=errf)
```

when `outf`/`errf` is either None or a file descriptor (different files for `stdout`/`stderr`).

Is there any way I can execute each exe so that the stdout and stderr will be written to the files and terminal together?

Comment: [asyncio version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960956/4279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously)

Answer (score 28):

The [`call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function is just [`Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py?view=markup). You could call `Popen` directly and use `stdout=PIPE` argument to read from `p.stdout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread


def tee(infile, *files):
    """Print `infile` to `files` in a separate thread."""

    def fanout(infile, *files):
        with infile:
            for line in iter(infile.readline, b""):
                for f in files:
                    f.write(line)

    t = Thread(target=fanout, args=(infile,) + files)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t


def teed_call(cmd_args, **kwargs):
    stdout, stderr = [kwargs.pop(s, None) for s in ["stdout", "stderr"]]
    p = Popen(
        cmd_args,
        stdout=PIPE if stdout is not None else None,
        stderr=PIPE if stderr is not None else None,
        **kwargs
    )
    threads = []
    if stdout is not None:
        threads.append(
            tee(p.stdout, stdout, getattr(sys.stdout, "buffer", sys.stdout))
        )
    if stderr is not None:
        threads.append(
            tee(p.stderr, stderr, getattr(sys.stderr, "buffer", sys.stderr))
        )
    for t in threads:
        t.join()  # wait for IO completion
    return p.wait()


outf, errf = open("out.txt", "wb"), open("err.txt", "wb")
assert not teed_call(["cat", __file__], stdout=None, stderr=errf)
assert not teed_call(["echo", "abc"], stdout=outf, stderr=errf, bufsize=0)
assert teed_call(["gcc", "a b"], close_fds=True, stdout=outf, stderr=errf)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but it doesn't work. the external process only sees OS-level file handles (the number you get
from the fileno() method on your file objects). see http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/541085-extend-file-type

Comment: thanks, what would you do if instead of subprocess.Call I'de like to run multiple execs using subprocess.Popen (and not Call), where each exec writes to a different file and to the terminal

Comment: @user515766: the solution is the same: set `stdout`, `stderr` to `PIPE` and call `tee()` when you'd like to write to more than one place.

Comment: somebody has deleted comments that demonstrate that the first comment ("doesn't work") is wrong. It confuses`subprocess.call` and the function `call` (different) that is called `teed_call` now to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: I've made the code in the answer to be Python 2/3 compatible. (it was pure Python 2 solution in 2011)

Comment: I had to add this to get the example to work:



`if isinstance(f, io.TextIOBase):
                        f.write(str(line))
                    else:
                        f.write(line)`

Comment: @channon: `str` is likely a wrong thing to do. Notice, the code in the answer open files in *binary* mode. If you want support text files, specify an appropriate for your case character encoding such as utf-8, cp437, etc  (or pass `text=True` if you want the `subprocess` module to chose it for you)$ Also, `sys.stdout.buffer` instead of `sys.stdout` should be used in binary mode on Python 3 (perhaps, this part causes the error)

Comment: Yes you are correct, the better way is to use the`sys.stdout.buffer`. Now the test cases provided pass as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
https://github.com/waszil/subpiper

In your callbacks you can do whatever you like, log, write to file, print, etc. It also supports non-blocking mode.

```
from subpiper import subpiper

def my_stdout_callback(line: str):
    print(f'STDOUT: {line}')

def my_stderr_callback(line: str):
    print(f'STDERR: {line}')

my_additional_path_list = [r'c:\important_location']

retcode = subpiper(cmd='echo magic',
                   stdout_callback=my_stdout_callback,
                   stderr_callback=my_stderr_callback,
                   add_path_list=my_additional_path_list)
```

Comment: I tried this with cmd='python3 run2.py' but get an error. Am I missing something how to send run2.py as a parameter: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3 run2.py': 'python3 run2.py'