# Get STDOUT, STDERR of all running processes in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm a Python noob.

Is there a way to get the STDOUT and STDERR of all running processes in Python? Some processes exit after a long time and their status is constantly being written to STDOUT.

Comment: do you mean literally all running proceses, or just processes you create while running your program? do you create multiple processes? Two major strategies are to create a thread for each process so that they run in parallel or to create files and redirect process output there.

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18345099/841339

Comment: Those are two *very* different questions.

Answer (score 0):

To get subprocess output line by line without waiting for it to close:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
while True:
    o = p.stdout.readline()
    if not o:
        break
    print o
```

you can use p.stdout.read(n) if want to read every 'n' characters from the process.

Hope this helps.