# How to use a custom file-like object as subprocess stdout/stderr?

Tags: python, subprocess

Consider this code, where a `subprocess.Popen` is spawned. I'd like writes to the subprocess' `stdout` and `stderr` to go to my custom file-object's `.write()` method, however this isn't the case.

```python
import subprocess

class Printer:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, chunk):
        print('Writing:', chunk)

    def fileno(self):
        return 0

    def close(self):
        return

proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'echo Testing'], 
                        stdout=Printer(),
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.wait()
```

Why is the `.write()` method not used, and what is the use of specifying a `stdout=` parameter in this case?

Comment: Here's an example where a custom file-like object is used as subprocess stdout/stderr: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.  Valid values are **PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None**.

Using [`subprocess.PIPE`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'echo Testing'], 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print('Writing:', proc.stdout.read())
# OR  print('Writing:', proc.stdout.read().decode())
```

Comment: That works, however I need the `stdout` and `stderr` separate (should've been in question), and also in realtime. Also, why does my example not work, isn't it a file-like object?

Comment: @minerz029, As I quoted the documentation, the subprocess.Popen does not accept file-like object, but only `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, a file descriptor, a file object, `None`.

Comment: @minerz029, `for line in proc.stdout: print('Writing', line.decode())`

Comment: @minerz029, If you meant to write to stdout, the return value of the `fileno` should be `1`. Even if you changed to `1`, `write` method is not called. It is just written to stdout of current process.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. Maybe some future version of Python will support converting file-like objects into some sort of auto-populating pipe, but the crux of it is that the subprocess needs to have access to a file handle it can read without calling Python code somehow. This means it needs to be something that works at an OS level, meaning it is limited to a few possibilities:

- Inheriting stdin from the parent process (which happens when `stdin=None`)
- Taking input from a file (which happens when `stdin` is a file or an integer file handle)
- Taking input from a pipe (which happens when `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`)

Using a file-like object means you're going to have to read the data yourself and then feed it through a pipe.

For example:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sha256sum', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    chunk = filelike.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    proc.stdin.write(chunk)
    if len(chunk) < BLOCK_SIZE:
        break
proc.wait()
```