# handle stdin manualy for subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to make a Terminal Emulator and for that I need to handle `stdin/stdout/stder` to redirect them to a GUI

I already managed to handle `stdout and stderr`, the problem is for `stdin`.

I would like to have a function that is called every time `stdin` is read, so I could request input to the user.

I use

```py
subprocess.Popen("command", shell="True")
```

I tried using temp file and editing `read`, `readline` and `readlines` of the files but the problem is that if I understood correctly (from the source) `subprocess.Popen` takes the file and reopen it to use it.

I also tried creating custom file like objects but as I said before `subprocess.Popen` takes the file and try to reopen it but as my object is a fake file it does not work

**How could I create a stdinRedirector?**

Something like that

```py
class StdinRediector():
    def read():
        input = gui.ask_input()
        return input

subprocess.Popen(
    "command",
    shell="True",
    stdin=StdinRediector,
)
```

I don't ask for `stdout and stderr` as there is already answers here:

- [Display realtime output of a subprocess in a tkinter widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362372/display-realtime-output-of-a-subprocess-in-a-tkinter-widget)
- [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)
- [How to use a custom file-like object as subprocess stdout/stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035127/how-to-use-a-custom-file-like-object-as-subprocess-stdout-stderr)

**but these don't talk about `stdin` which is my problem.**

**THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE**

Comment: You must not define a `fileno()` method for something that isn't actually an OS-level file - anything that calls that method will expect to be able to pass its return value on to system calls that require a valid file handle.  Yes, this means that you won't be able to pass your objects directly to `subprocess` functions.  What you need to do is pass `subprocess.PIPE` for all three channels, and write code to transfer data between those pipes and your GUI.

Comment: but how can I overite the `read() ` of `subprocess.PIPE` in stdin

Comment: *overwrite the `read()` of `subprocess.PIPE` in stdin* -- huh? Why would you do that? Just have a thread that reads from the descriptors the completely normal way and updates the GUI when there's new content (reading a line at a time if that's good enough, or a byte at a time if you need more immediacy and can afford the extra overhead). The cheap/easy approach is just a separate thread for each descriptor, though `select`-style tools let you just have one thread that gets pinged when there's content on any of them.

Comment: When you assign `stdin` and `stdout`, that doesn't tell Python what to do when there's input or output available. Instead, it tells Python _how to wire up the stdin and stdout_. It has to be a real OS-level file, because only real files can be attached at the `fdup` layer. Hence, if you want it to be a file that can be read or written by Python, `subprocess.PIPE` is your only choice; how you write the code that reads and writes from that pipe is your choice.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978 is a useful example taken from a comment on one of the linked duplicates.

Comment: yes but it does not show me how to handle stdin and theses answers wich I'm "duplicate" does not talk about stdin wich is the actual problem