# Read subprocess stdout and stderr concurrently

Tags: python, io, subprocess, nonblocking

I'm trying to run a lengthy command within Python that outputs to both stdout and stderr. I'd like to poll the subprocess and write the output to separate files.

I tried the following, based on this answer [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

```
import subprocess

from Queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread

def send_cmd(cmd, shell=False):
    """
    Send cmd to the shell
    """
    if not isinstance(cmd, list): cmd = shlex.split(cmd)

    params = {'args'   : cmd,
              'stdout' : subprocess.PIPE,
              'stderr' : subprocess.PIPE,
              'shell'  : shell}

    proc = subprocess.Popen(**params)

    return proc

def monitor_command(process, stdout_log=os.devnull, stderr_log=os.devnull):
    """
    Monitor the process that is running, and log it if desired
    """
    def enqueue_output(out, queue):
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            queue.put(line)

    def setup_process(log_name, proc):
        FID = open(log_name, 'w')
        queue = Queue()
        thread = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(proc, queue))
        thread.daemon = True # Thread dies with program
        thread.start()

        return (queue, FID)

    def check_queues(queue_list, errors):
        for queue, FID in queue_list:
            try:
                line = queue.get_nowait()
                if 'error' in line.lower() or 'failed' in line.lower():
                    errors.append(line)
            except Empty:
                pass
            else:
                FID.write(line)

    errors = []
    queue_list = []

    for log, proc in [(stdout_log, process.stdout), (stderr_log, process.stderr)]:
        queue_list.append(setup_process(log, proc)

    while process.poll() is None:
        check_queues(queue_list, errors)

    while not queue_list[0][0].empty() or queue_list[1][0].empty():
        check_queues(queue_list, errors)

    for queue, FID in queue_list:
        FID.close()

return errors

process = send_cmd('long_program.exe')
errors  = monitor_command(process, stdout_log='stdout.log', stderr_log='stderr.log')
```

But it the output file for stdout is empty, and the output file for stderr is only a few lines long, whereas both should be quite large.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did that once.. here is some old code I wrote

```
class Process_Communicator():

    def join(self):
        self.te.join()
        self.to.join()
        self.running = False
        self.aggregator.join()
        self.ti.join()

    def enqueue_in(self):
        while self.running and self.p.stdin is not None:
            while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s) + '\n\r')
            pass

    def enqueue_output(self):
        if not self.p.stdout or self.p.stdout.closed:
            return
        out = self.p.stdout
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            self.qo.put(line)
        #    out.flush()

    def enqueue_err(self):
        if not self.p.stderr or self.p.stderr.closed:
            return
        err = self.p.stderr
        for line in iter(err.readline, b''):
            self.qe.put(line)

    def aggregate(self):
        while (self.running):
            self.update()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qe.not_empty:
                line = self.qe.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_err += line
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qo.not_empty:
                line = self.qo.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_out += line
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s))

    def get_stdout(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stdout(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def get_stderr(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stderr(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def __init__(self, subp):
        '''This is a simple class that collects and aggregates the
        output from a subprocess so that you can more reliably use
        the class without having to block for subprocess.communicate.'''
        self.p = subp
        self.unbblocked_out = ""
        self.unbblocked_err = ""
        self.running = True
        self.qo = Queue.Queue()
        self.to = threading.Thread(name="out_read",
                                    target=self.enqueue_output,
                                    args=())
        self.to.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.to.start()

        self.qe = Queue.Queue()
        self.te = threading.Thread(name="err_read",
                                   target=self.enqueue_err,
                                   args=())
        self.te.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.te.start()

        self.stdin_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.aggregator = threading.Thread(name="aggregate",
                                           target=self.aggregate,
                                           args=())
        self.aggregator.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.aggregator.start()
        pass
```

You may not need the whole example, but feel free to cut copy and paste what you need.  It's also important to show how I did the threading.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks more complicated than the task requires. I don't see why do you need to call `process.poll()` or `queue.get_nowait()` here. To deliver subprocess' stdout/stderr to several sinks; you could start with [`teed_call()` that accepts arbitrary file-like objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985080/4279): you could pass logfiles and special file-like objects that accumulates `errors` in theirs `.write()` methods.

To fix your code with minimal changes; you should call `.join()` on the reader threads (even if `process.poll()` is *not* `None` i.e., the subprocess exited; there could be some pending output. Joining reader's threads ensures that all output is read).