# How do I retrieve stderr for a shell command with a large data buffer?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.x

Python subprocess module states regarding the [communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function:

> Note
>
> The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the
>   data size is large or unlimited.

How can I execute a process that reads a lot of data (e.g. communicate() is contraindicated) and yet still have access to the stderr output?

Comment: Are you asking how to read both stdout/stderr without storing the whole output in memory i.e., without `.communicate()`? The simplest portable way would be to use threads e.g., see [`teed_call()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4985080/4279)

Comment: I was under the (false) impression that you could only access stderr output if you previously used communicate(). stderr can actually simply be retrieved using dump_proc.stderr.read().

Comment: the issue with using `proc.stderr.read()` is that if you also use `proc.stdout.read()` then your process may deadlock if it generates enough output to fill the corresponding pipe buffer that is why you need threads, or non-blocking pipes, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get possibly unlimited subprocess' stdout/stderr output separately as soon as it becomes available, you could use [`twisted` spawnProcess()](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class ProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print 'got stdout:', data
    def errReceived(self, data):
        print 'got stderr:', data
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        reactor.stop()

process = ProcessProtocol()
reactor.spawnProcess(process, 'cmd', ['cmd', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'])
reactor.run()
```

An alternative is to use threads e.g., [`teed_call()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985080/4279) or use OS specific code e.g., [`fcntl` module to make the pipes non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810703/4279) on POSIX systems or use [Overlapped I/O with named pipes on Windows](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#l266).

Answer (score 1):

"communicate()" solves this problem by using threads. That means, you need an extra stderr reading thread, while doing the main work (reading stdout) in the main thread. Alternatively you can use *select.select*, but this doesn't work with windows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your type of problem you may be able to rearrange the code to pipe the `stderr` process into your python code. [This page](http://axialcorps.com/2013/09/27/dont-slurp-how-to-read-files-in-python/) has some pointers.