# How do you search subprocess output in Python for a specific word?

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I'm trying to search through a variable's output to find a specific word, then have that trigger a response if True.

```
variable = subprocess.call(["some", "command", "here"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for word in variable:
    if word == "myword":
        print "something something"
```

I'm sure I'm missing something big here, but I just can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance for setting me straight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap subprocess' stdout/stderr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335587/wrap-subprocess-stdout-stderr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the stdout of the process, you can do something like that:

```
mainProcess = subprocess.Popen(['python', file, param], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
communicateRes = mainProcess.communicate() 
stdOutValue, stdErrValue = communicateRes

# you can split by any value, here is by space
my_output_list = stdOutValue.split(" ")

# after the split we have a list of string in my_output_list 
for word in my_output_list :
    if word == "myword":
        print "something something"
```

This is for stdout, you can check the stderr also, Also here is some info about [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

Comment: If you use `.split()` (no argument) then it splits on *any whitespace*. You could use `re.findall(r"\w+", text)` to find words in a text. Note: `.communicate()` doesn't work if the output is large or unlimited. [You could read line by line instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280092/4279).

Comment: the loop could be replaced by `if "myword" in my_output_list:` or `n = my_output_list.count("myword")` if multiple occurences are possible

Answer (score 2):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). That returns the standard output from the process. `call` only returns the exit status. (You'll want to call `split` or `splitlines` on the output.)

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` returns the process'es exit code, not its stdout. There's an example on [this help page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) for how to capture a command's output. If you plan to do something more sophisticated with the subprocess, [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) might be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If the output may be possibly unlimited then you shouldn't use `.communicate()` to avoid running out of computer memory. You could read subprocess' output line by line instead:

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

word = "myword"
p = Popen(["some", "command", "here"], 
          stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in p.stdout: 
    if word in line:
       for _ in range(re.findall(r"\w+", line).count(word)):
           print("something something")
```

Note: `stderr` is not redirected. If you leave `stderr=PIPE` without reading from `p.stderr` later then the process may block forever if it generates enough output on stderr to fill its OS pipe buffer. See [this answer if you want to get both stdout/stderr separately in the unlimited case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279231/4279).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should use `Popen` or `check_output` to get the process output, and then use the `communicate()` method to get stdout and stderr and search for your word in these variables:

```
variable = subprocess.Popen(["some", "command", "here"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = variable.communicate()
if (word in stdout) or (word in stderr):
    print "something something"
```