# Python stream subprocess stdout/stderr in real-time

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess

I want to spawn multiple subprocesses and run them in parallel. I have a function which looks mostly like this:

```
def stream_command(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while proc.poll() is None:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        sys.stdout.write('[%s]: %s' % (command, line))
    return proc.poll()
```

I then can run multiple in parallel (roughly) with this:

```
def stream_commands(commands):
    threads = []
    for command in commands:
        target = lambda: stream_command(command)
        thread = Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    while True:
        if any(t.is_alive() for t in threads):
            continue
        else:
            break
```

The issue, however, is that in my `stream_command` function I am *blocking* on a call to `proc.stdout.readline()`. That means a couple of things: first of all, if the process never writes to `stdout`, that function will hang forever (even if the subprocess terminates, for example). Secondly, I can't separately respond to the `stdout` and `stderr` of the process (I would have to first blocking read to one, and then to the other... which would be very unlikely to work). What I would like to do is something akin to what I would write in `node.js`:

```
def stream_command(command):
    def on_stdout(line):
        sys.stdout.write('[%s]: %s' % (command, line))
    def on_stderr(line):
        sys.stdout.write('[%s (STDERR)]: %s' % (command, line))
    proc = asyncprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),
            on_stdout=on_stdout,
            on_stderr=on_stderr
    )
    return proc.wait()
```

Where of course `asyncprocess` is some fictitious process module that lets me start subprocesses and pass handler functions for `stdout` and `stderr`.

So, is there anything akin to the `asyncprocess` module I have above, or failing that, is there any simple way to respond *asynchronously* to the events of a subprocess in python?

By the way, I should note that I'm using python 2.7. There seems to be some stuff for python3 via the `asyncio` library, but unfortunately that doesn't work here, AFAIK.

Comment: Do you want to process the output at all? If not, don't redirect stdout/err to pipes.

Comment: Yes, I do: as you can see, I want to prepend each line with the command the line was produced by, or with that command plus `(STDERR)` if the line is from stderr. And in general, I want to support arbitrary processing of the lines, in real-time (the actual `stream_command` function I'm writing takes a handler function to process the lines however the user desires)

Comment: `proc.stdout.readline()` returns an empty string when the program terminates, so you don't have a problem. Its more common to do `for line in proc.stdout` than the `while proc.poll()` thing, but both work. But your existing code works.

Comment: ... except it doesn't work, for the reasons I describe. Perhaps I don't need to worry about `readline()` not returning, but the issue of separately and asynchronously responding to `stdout` and `stderr` remains.

Comment: Oh, you were setting `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` so I was confused.

Comment: you could pass file-like objects  to [`teed_call()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4985080/4279). Put into their `.write()` methods whatever you want to put into `on_stdX()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a thread per data stream. Assuming you want `stream_commands` to block until all of the commands complete, you can do this:

```
stdout_lock = threading.Lock()

def pipe_to_stdout(preamble, pipe):
    for line in pipe:
        with stdout_lock:
            sys.stdout.write(preamble + line)

def stream_commands(commands):
    threads = []
    procs = []
    try:
        for command in commands:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            procs.append(proc)
            out_thread = Thread(target=target, args=('[stdout]: ', proc.stdout)
            err_thread = Thread(target=target, args=('[stderr]: ', proc.stderr)
            out_thread.start()
            err_thread.start()
            threads.append(out_thread)
            threads.append(err_thread)
    finally:
        for proc in procs:
            proc.wait()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to block until the subprocess has finished before writing anything... :(

Comment: Yeah, that's because subprocess pipes aren't pseudo-terminals. You can get around that by using `ptry.openpty` for the pipes or perhaps even look at the `pexpect` module.

Comment: OK but that still really doesn't answer my question, sorry. It's an important requirement that I can view the output in real-time (otherwise I could simply use `proc.communicate()`). I *am* able to do this with the technique I put in my initial question; I'm simply unable to separately respond to stdout and stderr.