# None in redirected stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have this part of following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe', '-m', 'robot', '-d', logs_directory, input_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    output = sys.stdout.write(line)
    #sys.stdout.write(line)
print "\n\n"
print "************************************************"
print  output
print "\n\n"
print "************************************************"
print "\n\n"
```

But 'output' variable in console shows 'none'

```
************************************************
None



************************************************
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write(line)` returns the number of characters written on stdout.

You could write your loop like this:

```py
output = ""
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    output += line
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

imho you can also remove the `sys.stdout.write(line)` part. But I don't know what you are meant to do with it so...

Comment: sys.stdout.write(line) does return a value. It returns the number of characters written on stdout.

Comment: 1- `sys.stdout.write()` returns `None` on Python 2 by default. 2- `output += line` may produce quadratic behavior on some Python implementations. You could use `lines = []; ... lines.append(line) ... output = ''.join(lines)` instead (linear behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Try `output += line` instead of `output = sys.stdout.write(line)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try function `check_output`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

You can try:

```
cmd = ['C:/Python27/python.exe', '-m', 'robot', '-d', logs_directory, input_file]
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print output
```

In most of the cases, it can do the job simply.

For details, you may want to reference to [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: Correct, but i also want to print results to console, check_output is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: I don't understand why you think `check_output` is not sufficient. You just assign its return value to a variable then print to console.

Comment: that won't be 'realtime' print. I'll get console output when subprocess will end. I want to have console output so i can see progress sof subprocess

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks!