# Subprocess.Popen: cloning stdout and stderr both to terminal and variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Is it possible to modify code below to have printout from 'stdout 'and 'stderr':

- printed on the **terminal** (in real time),
- and finally stored in **outs** and **errs** variables?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

def run_cmd(command, cwd=None):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, cwd=cwd, shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    outs, errs = p.communicate()
    rc = p.returncode
    outs = outs.decode('utf-8')
    errs = errs.decode('utf-8')

    return (rc, (outs, errs))
```

Thanks to @unutbu, special thanks for @j-f-sebastian, final function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from queue import Queue
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading import Thread


def read_output(pipe, funcs):
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
        for func in funcs:
            func(line.decode('utf-8'))
    pipe.close()


def write_output(get):
    for line in iter(get, None):
        sys.stdout.write(line)


def run_cmd(command, cwd=None, passthrough=True):
    outs, errs = None, None

    proc = Popen(
        command,
        cwd=cwd,
        shell=False,
        close_fds=True,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE,
        bufsize=1
        )

    if passthrough:

        outs, errs = [], []

        q = Queue()

        stdout_thread = Thread(
            target=read_output, args=(proc.stdout, [q.put, outs.append])
            )

        stderr_thread = Thread(
            target=read_output, args=(proc.stderr, [q.put, errs.append])
            )

        writer_thread = Thread(
            target=write_output, args=(q.get,)
            )

        for t in (stdout_thread, stderr_thread, writer_thread):
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

        proc.wait()

        for t in (stdout_thread, stderr_thread):
            t.join()

        q.put(None)

        outs = ' '.join(outs)
        errs = ' '.join(errs)

    else:

        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
        outs = '' if outs == None else outs.decode('utf-8')
        errs = '' if errs == None else errs.decode('utf-8')

    rc = proc.returncode

    return (rc, (outs, errs))
```

Comment: The code example does store `outs` and `errs` and returns them... To print to the terminal, simply `if outs: print outs` `if errs: print errs`

Comment: @bnlucas Thanks, but as I stated in first point: the output should be printed in REAL TIME to terminal, like as without PIPEing.

Comment: If you need Python 3 code; add [tag:python-3.x] tag (i see python3 in the shebang). Your code as written will leave reading threads hanging. In Python 3 `''` is a Unicode literal, but `pipe.readline()` returns bytes by default (`'' != b""` on Python 3). If you fix it then the writer thread won't end, because nothing puts `""` into the queue.

Comment: related: [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap subprocess' stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335587/wrap-subprocess-stdout-stderr)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could spawn threads to read the stdout and stderr pipes, write to a common queue, and append to lists. Then use a third thread to print items from the queue.

```
import time
import Queue
import sys
import threading
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE


def read_output(pipe, funcs):
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, ''):
        for func in funcs:
            func(line)
            # time.sleep(1)
    pipe.close()

def write_output(get):
    for line in iter(get, None):
        sys.stdout.write(line)

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['random_print.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True, bufsize=1)
q = Queue.Queue()
out, err = [], []
tout = threading.Thread(
    target=read_output, args=(process.stdout, [q.put, out.append]))
terr = threading.Thread(
    target=read_output, args=(process.stderr, [q.put, err.append]))
twrite = threading.Thread(target=write_output, args=(q.get,))
for t in (tout, terr, twrite):
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
process.wait()
for t in (tout, terr):
    t.join()
q.put(None)
print(out)
print(err)
```

The reason for using the third thread -- instead of letting the first two threads both print directly to the terminal -- is to prevent both print statements from occurring concurrently, which can result in sometimes garbled text.

---

The above calls `random_print.py`, which prints to stdout and stderr at random:

```
import sys
import time
import random

for i in range(50):
    f = random.choice([sys.stdout,sys.stderr])
    f.write(str(i)+'\n')
    f.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

---

This solution borrows code and ideas from [J. F. Sebastian, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/190597).

---

Here is an alternative solution for Unix-like systems, using `select.select`:

```
import collections
import select
import fcntl
import os
import time
import Queue
import sys
import threading
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE

def make_async(fd):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730201/190597
    '''add the O_NONBLOCK flag to a file descriptor'''
    fcntl.fcntl(
        fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK)

def read_async(fd):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730201/190597
    '''read some data from a file descriptor, ignoring EAGAIN errors'''
    # time.sleep(1)
    try:
        return fd.read()
    except IOError, e:
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
            raise e
        else:
            return ''

def write_output(fds, outmap):
    for fd in fds:
        line = read_async(fd)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        outmap[fd.fileno()].append(line)

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['random_print.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)

make_async(process.stdout)
make_async(process.stderr)
outmap = collections.defaultdict(list)
while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [], [])
    write_output(rlist, outmap)
    if process.poll() is not None:
        write_output([process.stdout, process.stderr], outmap)
        break

fileno = {'stdout': process.stdout.fileno(),
          'stderr': process.stderr.fileno()}

print(outmap[fileno['stdout']])
print(outmap[fileno['stderr']])
```

This solution uses code and ideas from [Adam Rosenfield's post, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730201/190597).

Comment: you could add `q.put(None)` after `process.wait()` and exit the 3rd thread on `None` e.g., `for line in iter(get, None):`. Also `pipe.close()` is missing.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the corrections. Suppose `read_output` for some reason does not keep pace with the output being written to `pipe`. (I try to simulate that with a `time.sleep(1)` above). When the `time.sleep(1)` is uncommented, `out` and `err` fail to collect all the output before `process.wait()` completes. Do you know a way to guarantee that `out` and `err` get all the output?

Comment: `t{err,out}.join()` before `put(None)`. btw, to get lines in "real time", `bufsize=1` might help (ignoring `block-buffering issue)

Answer (score 26):

To capture and display at the same time both stdout and stderr from a child process line by line in a single thread, you could use asynchronous I/O:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import os
import sys
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE

@asyncio.coroutine
def read_stream_and_display(stream, display):
    """Read from stream line by line until EOF, display, and capture the lines.

    """
    output = []
    while True:
        line = yield from stream.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        output.append(line)
        display(line) # assume it doesn't block
    return b''.join(output)

@asyncio.coroutine
def read_and_display(*cmd):
    """Capture cmd's stdout, stderr while displaying them as they arrive
    (line by line).

    """
    # start process
    process = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    # read child's stdout/stderr concurrently (capture and display)
    try:
        stdout, stderr = yield from asyncio.gather(
            read_stream_and_display(process.stdout, sys.stdout.buffer.write),
            read_stream_and_display(process.stderr, sys.stderr.buffer.write))
    except Exception:
        process.kill()
        raise
    finally:
        # wait for the process to exit
        rc = yield from process.wait()
    return rc, stdout, stderr

# run the event loop
if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
rc, *output = loop.run_until_complete(read_and_display(*cmd))
loop.close()
```

Comment: This code looks good, could you add a version for Python 2.7?

Comment: @kinORnirvana: `asyncio` works only on Python 3.3+ There is `trollius`—a Python 2 clone but [it is deprecated](http://trollius.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: Nice work, J.F! I just "borrowed" your code for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41284244/4014959). If you have any comments, suggestions, &/or a better answer, they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that once the loop is closed doing `get_event_loop` will get you the same closed loop which cannot be re-used as is (`event loop is closed` message). I ended up doing `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` to get a fresh event loop.

Comment: I was running this code in a Jupyter notebook. I was getting an `AttributeError` because `sys.stdout.buffer` no longer existed. This helped clear it up: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr When in a Jupyter notebook I used `sys.stdout.write` in lieu of `sys.stdout.buffer.write`and the output appeared in the notebook logging output.

Comment: I found that this displays all the ouptut from stderr, then all the output from stdout.

Comment: @DanHook It is the block-buffering issue for redirected streams. [Python subprocess PIPE blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35573778/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version for your `run_cmd` function using `asyncio` in Python 3.11:

```
import asyncio
import io
import sys
from subprocess import SubprocessError


# Maximum number of bytes to read at once from the 'asyncio.subprocess.PIPE'
_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

async def run_cmd_async(command, cwd=None, check=False):
    stdout_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    stderr_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    process = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command,
        cwd=cwd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    async def write_stdout() -> None:
        assert process.stdout is not None
        while chunk := await process.stdout.read(_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE):
            stdout_buffer.write(chunk)
            print(chunk.decode(), end="", flush=True)

    async def write_stderr() -> None:
        assert process.stderr is not None
        while chunk := await process.stderr.read(_MAX_BUFFER_CHUNK_SIZE):
            stderr_buffer.write(chunk)
            print(chunk.decode(), file=sys.stderr, end="", flush=True)

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as task_group:
        task_group.create_task(write_stdout())
        task_group.create_task(write_stderr())

        exit_code = await process.wait()
        if check and exit_code != 0:
            raise SubprocessError(
                f"Command '{command}' returned non-zero exit status {exit_code}."
            )
    return exit_code, (stdout_buffer.getvalue().decode(),
                       stderr_buffer.getvalue().decode())


def run_cmd(command, cwd=None, check=False):
    return asyncio.run(run_cmd_async(command, cwd=cwd, check=check))
```

Answer (score 0):

To stream live output (stdout and stderr) of a subprocess to the terminal, as well as to variables, you can spawn two threads to handle the streams concurrently.

Adapted from my more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76634163/5511061):

```py
import logging
from collections import deque
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from subprocess import PIPE, CalledProcessError, CompletedProcess, Popen


def stream_command(
    args,
    *,
    stdout_handler=logging.info,
    stderr_handler=logging.error,
    check=True,
    text=True,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    **kwargs,
):
    """Mimic subprocess.run, while processing the command output in real time."""
    with Popen(args, text=text, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs) as process:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:  # two threads to handle the streams
            exhaust = partial(pool.submit, partial(deque, maxlen=0))
            exhaust(stdout_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stdout)
            exhaust(stderr_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stderr)
    retcode = process.poll()
    if check and retcode:
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args)
    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode)
```

Call with custom handlers:

```py
outs, errs = [], []
def stdout_handler(line):
    outs.append(line)
    print(line)
def stderr_handler(line):
    errs.append(line)
    print(line)

stream_command(
    ["echo", "test"],
    stdout_handler=stdout_handler,
    stderr_handler=stderr_handler,
)
# test
print(outs)
# ['test']
```